# How do I seperate these two "windows"?

Tags: customization

I'm new to Blender and I've got almost no clue of what I'm messing around with, but I do understand the common concepts and I'm getting some progress done.

With that said: I've got a more of a personal preference issue, I'd like to separate these two windows ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ekC.png)) as I've got a lot of objects to manage while editing the model. How can I do so?

[image: Blender Screenshot]

Comment: you mean the 2 windows on the right? If you want to collapse the top window, select the top right corner of the bottom window and drag and drop up, then down, and release

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So as You could see on the image above, the "lined" corners are crucial for window operations. Every window has *TWO* of them, so look for the **top right** and **bottom left** corners as circled green on the picture.

1) Drag that corner **to** the edge of the window to collapse the one next to it (bottom circle on the image)

2) Drag that corner **from** the edge to make a new one (top circle on the image)

As You could see I created new BIG windows in the center instead of that small on the right which seems that You want to achieve.

Hope it helps buddy, Sincerely, JayM